# How do you find the size of an Android App on the device?

Tags: android, file, size

I need to find the size of a JAR that I added to an application, and I want to test the size with it installed on the device, and without, to get the true size it adds when running on an android device. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to do it only one time (i.e. login and check the size) or do you need to test it programmatically (i.e. from the code of your application, to log it on logcat/show to the user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings -> Applications -> All`

Select the application in question. The next screen shows the total size, the application size, and the data size.